# codeigniter: where do entities go?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, entities

I was wondering what should I do with my entities? For example, a class named Articles, with a few datamembers (name/title/date) and getters & setters. I could add these to my Articles datamember, but it's better practice to seperate those. So what do you think?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by saying "I could add these to my Articles datamember, but it's better practice to seperate those"? I suppose you should extend your Article class from Model class (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html) and go on.

Comment: by that i mean adding the datamembers to the model, like on the example, but is it not better to separate entities?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'entities'?

Comment: a class with datamembers and getters and setters (only)

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about what CodeIgniter considers a  "model", in the model-view-controller paradigm

Comment: To avoid any confusion from @maegar comment, what Sled describes is NOT a codeigniter (or MVC) 'model'. An MVC model will contain business logic and is much more than just an entity class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i usually do this:

1.- create my entity classes in /system/application/classes

```
class MyEntity {
}
```

2.- define a constant to point to that folder on /system/application/config/constants.php

```
define('CLASSES_DIR', APPPATH . "classes/");
```

3.- include the entities classes from the models:

```
require_once(CLASSES_DIR  . "MyEntity.php");

class MyModel extends Model {

   function test() {
      $entity = new MyEntity();
      $entity->doSomeStuff();
   }

}
```

That won't break your mvc structure, and keeps for entities classes separated. Hope that helps!

Comment: This seems like the best solution. I asked this question recently at http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/166650/ but didn't get any solid replies.

Answer (score 4):

I liked @ilbesculpi's solution, but I customized it a bit using a namespace rather than using a constant and `require_once`. Here is my version:

1) Create my entity classes in /system/application/entities.

```
namespace MyApplication\Entities;

class ArticlesEntity
{
    function doSomeStuff()
    {
        // Your code here...
    }
}
```

2) Include my entity class in my model via a `using` statement.

```
use MyApplication\Entities\ArticlesEntity;

class ArticlesModel extends CI_Model
{
    function test() 
    {
      $entity = new ArticlesEntity();
      $ArticlesEntity->doSomeStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is more elegant solution. However, I think it needs some autoloading mechanism like PSR-4.

Comment: CodeIgniter4 will have support for working with entities: https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/models/entities.html

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter models use the singleton pattern. You can create libraries or use $foo = new Some_Model if you like, remember that its all just PHP :)

Comment: Doesn't really work well if you want, say, a list of products. All you are doing is creating a function collection.

Comment: Right, CodeIgniter models are generally dumb, thin, singletons. But you can use plain old PHP to do things however you like.